# Navigator not passing parameters to scene

Tags: react-native

So, I have a simple button (TouchableHighlight) calling the following function:

```js
showMovie() {

        this.props.navigator.push({
            name: 'MovieScreen',
            index: 1,
            movie: "terminator"
        });
    }
```

It works as expected, pushing the MovieScreen scene defined in a different file.

In the MovieScreen constructor I have:

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props.movie);
}
```

All I get is "undefined".

I tried with:  console.log(this.props.passProps.movie); => undefined.

I tried putting the "movie" parameter in a passProps object => undefined.

I can't seem to pass parameters to a scene. If I print this.props I can't find anywhere the "movie" variable, but this.props is there and it contains the navigator object and everything.

Judging from the examples around the web, I'm doing exactly what thousands of people do, with the difference that mine doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong?

**More details as requested**

This is how my app is composed:

- index.android.js
- HomepageScreen.js
- MovieScreen.js

**index.android.js**

```js
class MovieApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                initialRoute={{ name: 'HomepageScreen', title: 'My Initial Scene', index: 0 }}
                renderScene={ this.renderScene }
            />
        );
    }

    renderScene(route, navigator) {
        if (route.name == 'HomepageScreen') {
            return <HomepageScreen navigator={navigator} />
        }

        if (route.name == 'MovieScreen') {
            return <MovieScreen navigator={navigator} />
        }
    }
}
```

**HomepageScreen.js**

```js
export default class HomepageScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var navigator = this.props.navigator;
      
    render() {
      return(                           
        <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this.showMovie.bind(this)}>
                                    <View style={Style.movieButton}>
                                    <Text style={Style.textStyle1}>Asd</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
        );
    }

    showMovie() {

        this.props.navigator.push({
            name: 'MovieScreen',
            index: 1,
            movie: "terminator"
        });
    }

}
```

**MovieScreen.js**

```js
export default class MovieScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log(this.props.movie);
    }
  
  .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (route.name == 'HomepageScreen') {
        return <HomepageScreen navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />
    }

    if (route.name == 'MovieScreen') {
        return <MovieScreen navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />
    }
}
```

And passing the props like this:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    name: 'MovieScreen',
    index: 1,
    passProps: {
      movie: "terminator"
    }
});
```

Comment: Sure. I added the files to the post.

Comment: Didn't realize I left my comment in an answer block! I just updated the answer above, let me know if that works.

Comment: Thank you mate. It works now. I don't know if many things don't work because they keep changing fast, but sometimes even the newest guides on the web don't work very well. Thanks again.